# ¿Cómo iterar cierta cantidad de veces desde la entrada estándar a partir de una lista?

Tags: python

Quiero iterar a partir de una lista en la entrada estándar estos datos:

```
cosas=['Monedas', 'Pasteles', 'Patos']
for i in cosas:
    cosas[i].append(int(input('Ingrese el valor total de sus {i}: ')))
```

Pero me arroja este error: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

¿Me pueden explicar por qué ocurre este error y cómo puedo corregirlo? Agradezco mucho su apoyo, saludos!

Comment: Tu iteracion te devuelve el elemto más no el número o índice

Comment: ¿Cómo lo corrijo?

Comment: Ya tienes 2 respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu iteracion te devuelve el elemto más no el índice si quieres hacer eso solo debes de poner que iré en el rango de esa lista

```
for i in range(len(cosas)):
    cosas[i].append(int(input(f'Ingrese el valor total de sus {cosas[i]}: ')))
```

Pero esto dará un error ya que los elemtos no son listas, no estoy seguro de lo que quieres pero daré 2 ejemplos

**con listas**

```
#establecemos que cada elemento sea una lista 
cosas=[['Monedas'], ['Pasteles'], ['Patos']]
for i in range(len(cosas)):
    cosas[i].append(int(input(f'Ingrese el valor total de sus {cosas[i][0]}: ')))
```

**con diccionario**

```
#dicciinario con los listas vacías como valor 
cosas = {"Monedas":[],"Pasteles":[],"Patos":[]}
#ya no establecemos el rango ya que necesitamos las claves 
for i in cosas:
    cosas[i].append(int(input(f'Ingrese el valor total de sus {i}: ')))
```

Comment: Me quedó mucho más claro, pero tengo un detalle que no puedo solucionar, si yo quisiera eliminar el corchete (de la lista) al imprimir los datos almacenados en otra lista, o sea me imprime esto: `[[2], [4], [5]]`, de la lista por ejemplo `almacenado=[]`, ¿cómo haría para que solo me quedara `2, 4, 5`?

Comment: Intento esto pero no me funciona: `print(','.join(almacenado))`

Comment: Con un pequeño ciclo for `almacenados =[ i[0] for i in a]`, eso te lo devuelve alguna parte de mi código?

Comment: No, no me lo devuelve (en el caso de los diccionarios)

Comment: Ya lo entendí xd, se tiene que crear otra lista nueva y ahí se vuele a iterar para separar cada elemento y luego aplicar `print(*almacenado2, end = '')`

Comment: Si, eso en caso de las listas, pero recomiendo los diccionarios ya que son más fáciles de leer y entender, por último si una de las 2 respuestas solucionó tu problema aceptala

Answer (score 1):

**El problema**

La variable `i` recibe valores `Monedas`, `Pasteles` y `Patos`, pero `cosas` es una lista, por lo que su indice debe ser un entero como 0, 1, 2.

Para imprimir usas el formato `{i}`, pero te falto poner una "f" por delante del string para producir el reemplazo.

**Diseño**

El problema es que estás leyendo valores e intentando reemplazar la lista de nombres por una lista de valores. Para este problema lo mejor es usar un diccionario indexado por el nombre y cuyo contenido sea el valor dado por el usuario.

Entonces, puedes usar `cosas` de la siguiente manera:

```
cosas["Pasteles"] = 10 # Asignar el valor 10 a los Pasteles.
print(cosas["Monedas"]) # Imprime el valor de Monedas.
```

El código queda así:

```
from pprint import pprint

cosas={'Monedas': 0, 'Pasteles': 0, 'Patos': 0}
for i in cosas:
    cosas[i] = int(input(f'Ingrese el valor total de sus {i}: '))
pprint(cosas)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese el valor total de sus Monedas: 10
Ingrese el valor total de sus Pasteles: 20
Ingrese el valor total de sus Patos: 30
{'Monedas': 10, 'Pasteles': 20, 'Patos': 30}
```

De esta manera

Comment: Ok, me queda más claro, pero que lo no me queda claro es por qué utilizas pprint?

Comment: Es por mera estética?

Comment: Uso `pprint` por que así listas y diccionarios salen mas "entendibles", pero es cosa de gustos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Candid Moe!